# Error when calling .Net Web Service from Blackberry

Tags: web-services, blackberry

I'm calling a .Net Web Service which takes a complex type as a parameter (using KSoap2). I've done this before successfully so I decided to just copy my old code and paste it into a new method, replacing some code with code relevant to the current web service of course.

The only real difference I can see is that the URL to the new web service's .asmx is different.

The thing is I keep getting the following error:

(I get the following when SoapEnvelope.VER11)

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body     (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Fault>@1:338 in java.io.InputStreamReader@199cb474)
```

(And the following when SoapEnvelope.VER12)

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope}Envelope (position:START_TAG <{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}soap:Envelope>@1:207 in java.io.InputStreamReader@5b209e72
```

Why would the error message change like this depending on the version of SOAP I use?

I also tried printing out my envelope with HttpTransport.requestDump and I get the following:

```
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <postMessage xmlns="http://www.magnatech.com/" id="o0" c:root="1">
            <myMessage i:type="n0:Message" xmlns:n0="http://www.magnatech.com/">
                <messageContent i:type="d:string">HEY</messageContent>
                <userName i:type="d:string">TEST USERNAME</userName>
                <agentName i:type="d:string">TEST AGENT NAME</agentName>
                <userID i:type="d:string">0</userID>
                <agentID i:type="d:string">0</agentID>
                <fromAgent i:type="d:string">false</fromAgent>
                <messageID i:type="d:string"></messageID>
                <accountNumber i:type="d:string">TEST ACCOUNT</accountNumber>
            </myMessage>
        </postMessage>
    </v:Body>
```

Which looks fine, I actually did the same thing with the envelope from my other "WORKING" web service call and they are the same, except for the element names of course.

And finally, here is the output from HttpTransport.responseDump:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Could not deserialize Soap message</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

So obviously there is something wrong with the envelope as I'm sending it, yet I see nothing wrong with it.

What could be the problem? I've tried everything possible and am running out of ideas.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: let me know your code for getting this from web service? and if it is possible , provide me any sample link